# Extend Doctrine object class

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine, inheritance

I want to set additional methods for all my command line generated doctrine objects. Obviously I can put the methods into each object individually, however I'd much rather like for each object to inherit from one superclass where I put my additional methods. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation at [Doctrine: Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). You can create another Entity in which you can write the basic properties and functions that you would want to apply on each of your other Entities and the extend this entity in each of the other Entities you create. Please read carefully the docs at the given link.